# View's onDraw method get called again and again on Android 2.2

Tags: android, charts, ondraw

I am new on Android development and meet with a tough problem when trying to implement a graphic drawing on a View.

What I want to do is drawing a chart in a View. I put a View in a ScrollView and override the onDraw method of View and do drawing in onDraw. The most important thing is that the chart needs scroll functions. 
The View's onDraw method I override includes the coordinate calculation and many necessary elements drawing (line, dot, axis, label, etc) in a chart. 
As you can imagine, I calculate and draw the whole chart not only the visible area but the whole area including offscreen. 
Now the problem is that onDraw method get called again and again when I scroll the ScrollView, so that it causes a performance issue and the scroll view running very slow. I was trying to find a way to prevent the calling of onDraw after first call but no lucky. I have to calculate the same thing again and again once onDraw get called which is not necessary.

Do you guys have any answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  mScrollX and mScrollY to calculate which visible part of canvas need to be re-draw.

```
 /**
 * The offset, in pixels, by which the content of this view is scrolled
 * vertically.
 * {@hide}
 */
@ViewDebug.ExportedProperty
protected int mScrollY;

/**
 * The left padding in pixels, that is the distance in pixels between the
 * left edge of this view and the left edge of its content.
 * {@hide}
 */
@ViewDebug.ExportedProperty
protected int mPaddingLeft;
/**
 * The right padding in pixels, that is the distance in pixels between the
 * right edge of this view and the right edge of its content.
 * {@hide}
 */
@ViewDebug.ExportedProperty
protected int mPaddingRight;
/**
 * The top padding in pixels, that is the distance in pixels between the
 * top edge of this view and the top edge of its content.
 * {@hide}
 */
@ViewDebug.ExportedProperty
protected int mPaddingTop;
/**
 * The bottom padding in pixels, that is the distance in pixels between the
 * bottom edge of this view and the bottom edge of its content.
 * {@hide}
 */
@ViewDebug.ExportedProperty
protected int mPaddingBottom;
```

Comment: I hope you aren't using those, since they are not public APIs.  The public APIs to retrieve the scroll offset are: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getScrollX()

Comment: You mean I still need to recalculate the visible area? I prefer that it is calculated only one time after the view first shown to user because the whole canvas is same all the time while user scroll it, and I think it is wasting time to recalculate it and actually it causes the performance issue indeed even though I just draw a rectangle on it. Is there anyway to avoid calculating this again and again when scrolling?